# How to map call events to their return events for the same function

Tags: python, trace, sys

We can map `call` event of a function to its associated `return` event by comparing the function name of both the events obtained using `frame.f_code.co_name`. But it gets a bit difficult when we call the same function multiple times and it is indefinite when those call functions will return.
Consider the following example-

```py
import sys
import random
from time import sleep

def ourFunction():
    sleep(random.randrange(0,5))


def traceCalls(frame , event , args):
    
    if event not in ["call" , "return"]:
        return

    co = frame.f_code
    funcName = co.co_name

    if funcName != "ourFunction":
        return

    print(f"{event} - {funcName}")
    
    return  traceCalls
```

In the above example, Imagine that `ourFunction()` has been called 3 times on different threads running simultaneously. Now It is indefinite when each of those will return. In such a case, how can we keep track of which `call` event is associated with which `return` event?

Here, We can't use name of the function to relate `call` and `return` events. I tried to find unique properties of `frame` that can be used for distinguishing one `call` event from `another` but was not able to find any.

It would be great if somebody can suggest a robust way to keep track of `call` with the associated `return` events.

Comment: You seem to use no threads or async code so one function will only start after the previous has ended

Comment: Oh my bad, Yes I meant execution in threads only. Editing the question!
@mousetail I have added the context. Thanks for pointing it out. Can you suggest something now?